# La definición del informe '' no es válida. Al inicio del día. RDLC

Tags: c#, wpf, reportviewer

Tengo una aplicación `WPF` que genera a petición del usuario, una serie de archivos `PDF`. Utilizo para ello, `ReportViewer`, `RDLC` y `c#`. Tengo al menos 5 tipos de reportes, es decir, al menos 5 métodos distintos que cada uno de ellos genera un archivo `PDF` y lo guarda en el equipo local.

Durante todo el día, no tengo ningún problema al generar los archivos. Pero, es recurrente que al iniciar el día, desde las primeras solicitudes al generar los archivos, éstos no se generen. He guardado en un `log`, el mensaje de la excepción generada al producirse el error. Simplemente dice:

> La definición del informe '' no es válida.

Así tal cual sin el nombre del informe.

La única forma de poder solucionarlo, que no es eficiente, es reiniciando el equipo que tiene la aplicación. Al reiniciar, todo funciona bien.

Dato adicional. La aplicación estuvo en ejecución en un equipo con `Windows 10`, nunca presentó esta falla. La falla comenzó a presentarse una vez que la aplicación se instaló en un sistema `Windows Server 2019 Standard`. El tipo de procesamiento de los reportes es Local.

Lo único que se me ocurre es que llegué a un límite de generación de archivos la aplicación, pero lo que no entiendo es por qué ocurre siempre al inicio del día.

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

hay que buscar mas información del error para poder solucionarlo, porque no intentas colocar un try catch en cada método que genera cada reporte para que sepas porque reporte comenzar a hacer la revisión, y personaliza el error, usa el inner exception para buscar mas detalles de la excepción

```
        try
        {
            //lógica de generación de reporte
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception($"Informe: nombreInforme, Exception: {ex.Message} {Environment.NewLine} Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException.Message}");
        }
```

Comment: esto que explicas es una resolucion o es algo que deberia probar ? porque me suena mas a comenario que a respuesta

Comment: saludos leandro totalmente de acuerdo es un comentario no una respuesta, algo que probar pues no soluciona su problema... pues aun no sabemos de hecho cual es, pero no tenía suficiente reputación para añadirlo como comentario

Comment: Saludos, gracias por responder. En efecto, la pregunta es, ¿Qué recomiendan hacer para evitar el reinicio diario del servidor?

Gerard_93, en efecto, tengo la generación de los formatos dentro de bloques try y catch; el mensaje de la excepción es el que comenté : La definición del informe '' no es válida. EL mensaje de InnerException viene en blanco.

Comment: @AxelGeovanniLucas primero se debe dar con el motivo del error, no podemos recomendar que hacer sin saber que es, los try eran para que pudieses dar con el reporte que está generando el error, si ya sabes que reporte es, entonces yo revisaría el reporte desde report builder, haz una copia y cambia la extension a rdl para abrirlo con report builder y ejecutarlo manualmente, también puedes revisar los logs del servidor a la hora en que se genera el error en busca de mas detalles, dato extra: el error que mencionas se genera cuando se consulta el reporte no tiene que ver con exportarlo.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, recuerda que esta zona es para respuestas sobre la pregunta, si deseas preguntar aclaraciones o sugerencias, estas se realizan en los comentarios , revisar [answer],.saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es debido a que se están usando namespaces incompatibles tal y como explica Joyzhao-MSFT en [Report error on VS 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/993464/report-error-on-vs-2017).

Lo que debes haces es por lo general un downgrade de la versión del `sqlserver/reporting` de 2016 a 2008, en la primera linea del RDLC, esto lo haces abriendo el RDLC en un editor de texto:

```
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
```

Además de hacer el downgrade debes eliminar unos elemento que no están disponibles en la versión de 2016 y que el propio Visual Studio genera al editar en lo más mínimo el Reporte en su interfaz gráfica. Estos elemento son `ReportSections`, `ReportSection` y `ReportParametersLayout` (este ultimo con todo lo que contengan), aquí hay una [explicación más detallada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37548615/8916993) en inglés